# I want a ionic3 simple Wheel Picker

Tags: ionic3

I have tried https://github.com/raychenfj/ion-multi-picker,but must use component.I just want to click a button,then pop up a Wheel Picker. Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STmg2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a wheelpicker instead of using a component, you can use

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/wheelselector-plugin/

**Install :**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-wheel-selector-plugin
npm install --save @ionic-native/wheel-selector
```

Add `WheelSelector` to your app NgModule providers.

**Use :**

```
import { WheelSelector } from '@ionic-native/wheel-selector';


constructor(private selector: WheelSelector) { }

const data= [
    { description: "1" },
    { description: "2" },
    { description: "3" }
];

 selectANumber() {
   this.selector.show({
     title: "How Many?",
     items: [
       this.data
     ],
   }).then(
     result => {
       console.log(result[0].description + ' at index: ' + result[0].index);
     },
     err => console.log('Error: ', err)
     );
 }
```

Just call `selectANumber()` from your button `(click)` :

```
<button ion-button (click)="selectANumber()">Select a number</button>
```

Comment: But Android performance behavior is not  the same as IOS. Is there any solution？  Sorry for my english.

Comment: @HuiCheng what do you mean by performance is not the same ? I’ve been using this plugin for some apps and never encountered any issues

Comment: Hi, I add a picture about in android. I want the android interface style display the same with IOS